# Monitor an business flow from end to end in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

Does anyone know a good solution to monitor a business flow (end to end) in Azure, where the integration spans different types of components, such as REST APIs, queues, Biztalk various ERP systems/SaaS services.

I use Azure Monitor today, but the ability to handle business flows in a good way is lacking in its basic implementation.

Comment: Have you tried "Data" block?  You can use the 'data' block to retrieve the resource and then reference it in the 'module' block.

Comment: You can try out Serverless360 BAM, which addresses the exact use case by providing a Business tracking solution and it has first-hand support for Azure, BizTalk, and REST API services. https://www.serverless360.com/blog/azure-end-to-end-transaction-details-with-enhanced-visibility